# MetaMask - RPC Error: Resource unavailable

Tags: vite, metamask, ethers.js, web3modal

I'm getting an error while trying to get a Core wallet account. It happens when I reload the page. It should detect the account but it is not. I'm using Vite with web3modal and ethers. I also use Core wallet Avalanche Fuji test network.

Here is what console looks like:

[image: Error]

Here is my code for checking accounts:

```
const updateCurrentWalletAddress = async () => {
    const accounts = await window?.ethereum?.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts"
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)})

    if(accounts){
        setWalletAddress(accounts[0])
    }
}
```

Here is the useEffect hook for checking:

```
useEffect(() => {
    updateCurrentWalletAddress()
    window?.ethereum?.on("accountsChanged", updateCurrentWalletAddress)
}, []);
```

I tried clearing browser data, cache and cookies. I tried creating a new account. I tried uninstalling Core Wallet.

Answer (score 3):

The method name should be `eth_accounts` instead of `eth_requestAccounts`. This solved my problem.

Comment:  but wondering when did this changed? I'd used `eth_requestAccounts` before in many sample projects?

Comment: @millisami I don't know but it changed at latest release.